# There was a change on a submodule that I do not want to stage/commit. Unfortunately, I cannot restore it. What should I do?

Tags: git, dependency-management

I was fetching/pulling a dependency from an open-source project. I did this in order to update things. It was necessary to run the program.

While I was doing it some unwanted changes happened in the main repository build files. Git shows the changes that happened:

```
Changes are not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   _build/submodules/cl-webkit (new commits)
```

As I do `git diff`, I can see it is a simple change:

```
$ git diff _build/submodules/cl-webkit/
diff --git a/_build/submodules/cl-webkit b/_build/submodules/cl-webkit
index cfc4f01e..29aeb74d 160000
--- a/_build/submodules/cl-webkit
+++ b/_build/submodules/cl-webkit
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit cfc4f01ee806169d824750b4014653a93af9353d
+Subproject commit 29aeb74d854bd2ac52959ef3d793389d238636c5
```

The change stays as unstaged and uncommitted. If I try to restore them with:

```
$ git restore _build/submodules/cl-webkit/
```

I do not receive error messages. However, it does **not** work. After pressing `git status`, git shows things stay the same:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   _build/submodules/cl-webkit (new commits)
```

What should I do?

This is pretty annoying. If I do a Pull Request into the open-source project, I always need to certify if I accidentally added (staged) and committed this change. It happened at least twice and the maintainers asked me to revert the commit and push a PR without it.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to attach build artifacts as a submodule, and an even worse idea to add build artifacts to the main repository: all build artifacts, i.e., the entire `_build` directory, should usually be listed in `.gitignore` and not committed *anywhere*. (But that's not the answer to your question, it's just a general statement about build artifacts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command to update a submodule is `git submodule update`

```
git submodule update _build/submodules/cl-webkit
```

(I was also surprised that neither `git restore` nor `git checkout` worked)

---

Since a submodule is also a git repo, you can update it by running regular git commands from within that submodule :

```
# if you can afford to delete all changes, you can use 'reset --hard'
cd _build/submodules/cl-webkit
git reset --hard cfc4f01ee806169d824750b4014653a93af9353d
```

Comment: Thanks! This alone creates a branch `(HEAD detached from ....)`. What should I do then?

Comment: hmm, I think you should `cd` into the submodule, run `git checkout master` (or whatever branch you were following), then `git reset cfc4f01`  (`git reset --hard ...` if you are ok with deleting all changes). This will re-set your local copy to a state where your `master` branch lags behind the upstream branch.